# Sonar Analysis is very slow during 'load/download plugins'

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

During sonar scanner analysis within Gitlab CI/CD, sometimes the load/download plugins phase is very slow, taking 30 minutes or more. This problem is intermittent. See below the evidence that appears in the logs:

`15:32:51.902 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=2041911ms`

Already tried using maven, gradle and sonar scanner image, but either method to run the analysis this problem ocurrs.

Answer (score 1):

I identified that the culprit for the problem is the SonarQube server, we noticed high cpu usage on that server. The solution was to upgrade and now the slow analysis no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

And also make sure SonarQube server has enough disk space to run analysis.